# Python Dice Game Guidance

Tags: python, function

In my Python class, we are now doing remote projects and the most recent one has me stumped. We are to create a dice game that functions like so:
1. Enter your bet amount
2. The dice are then rolled, and the result is set as the 'point'
3. The dice are rolled again, with a 7 or 11 resulting in a win, a 2, 3, or 12 resulting in a loss, and any other outcome resulting in a reroll.

I could write this code, but we have been given a skeleton script and have to fit our solution to it. I'm struggling with this because of my limited experience with functions. I have tried to teach myself, but this skeleton script is really throwing me off. I'd appreciate any help, and I apologize if this question is not appropriate here. I'm not looking for someone to write my solution for me, just some guidance. Thanks in advance.

Here is the skeleton script:

```
import random

def enterBet(): # returns amount bet (1-1000)

def rollTheDice():  # returns die1, die2

def setPoint(bet):  # returns the outome of the game and the point

def playDice(bet, point):  # returns the outcome

OUTCOME_WIN = 1
OUTCOME_LOSE = 2
OUTCOME_REROLL = 3

def main():

    bet = enterBet()
    outcome, point = setPoint(bet)

    while outcome == OUTCOME_REROLL:
        outcome = playDice(bet,point)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is my best attempt so far:

```
import random

def enterBet(): # returns amount bet (1-1000)
    int(input("Please Enter Your Bet: "))

def rollTheDice():  # returns die1, die2
    die1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    die2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    return die1, die2

def setPoint(bet):  # returns the outome of the game and the point
    rollTheDice()
    point = die1 + die2
    print('You rolled a ' + point + '.')
    print('This is the new point.')
    return point, outcome

def playDice(bet, point):  # returns the outcome
    print('Point is: ' + point )
    if point == 7 or point == 11:
        outcome = OUTCOME_WIN

    elif point == 2 or point == 3 or roll == 12:
        outcome = OUTCOME_LOSE
    else:
        outcome = OUTCOME_REROLL
    return outcome

OUTCOME_WIN = 1
OUTCOME_LOSE = 2
OUTCOME_REROLL = 3

def main():

    bet = enterBet()
    outcome, point = setPoint(bet)

    while outcome == OUTCOME_REROLL:
        outcome = playDice(bet, point)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And here is the error I get:

```
Please Enter Your Bet: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/School/CSCI 256/Project 2/p1_2.py", line 43, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:/School/CSCI 256/Project 2/p1_2.py", line 37, in main
    outcome, point = setPoint(bet)
  File "D:/School/CSCI 256/Project 2/p1_2.py", line 13, in setPoint
    point = die1 + die2
NameError: name 'die1' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I should mention that I have been attempting to get this thing to work for 12+ hours, so I have attempted, but I get errors out the you-know-what because I am so unfamiliar with using functions in this way.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Are you trying to write enterBet, rollTheDice, etc...?

Comment: @Sheldon I guess my first point of confusion is this: Why does setPoint() not take in die1 and die2, and sum them to find the point? I am having trouble setting the point initially.

Comment: It seems likely to me that the idea is that setPoint function calls the rollTheDice function, and uses the return values to set the point.

Comment: @FlamFace I tried that, but after I've called it, I can't seem to sum them in setPoint() because it says those return values are not defined. I can post the code of my best attempt with the error if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't assigning the return value of `rollTheDice` to variables, so the interpreter doesn't know what `die1` and `die2` are. The names of those variables are local to the function itself, so you would have to define them in the `setPoint` function too. If you change it to something like:

```
def setPoint(bet):  # returns the outome of the game and the point
    die1, die2 = rollTheDice()
    point = die1 + die2
    print('You rolled a ' + point + '.')
    print('This is the new point.')
    return point, outcome
```

it should know about those variables. However, you will still have a problem with the `outcome` variable which is also not defined.

You seem to be returning the point and outcome variables in a different order than is expected too, so look out for that.

Comment: Thanks so much, I thought this was what I was doing wrong but didn't know how to do it correctly.

Comment: No worries at all. Getting used to the scope of variables, I.e. where the interpreter will know about them, can be tricky.